# How do I remove Windows 7 when I am dual booting Ubuntu 12.10 as well

Tags: boot, windows-7, uninstall

I would like to remove the Windows 7 OS and only use the Ubuntu 12.10 install.  Is there a way for it to work?

Comment: I'd try searching on how to remove windows from boot loader and afterwards just play with partitions via GParted.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a program called **OS-Uninstaller** here is the [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller) for an article at the Ubuntu Help Wiki that will teach you how to install and use it.